# bash: append new line/string/text if input string has 2 lines

Tags: string, bash, sed, pipe, chain

i got following output and want to test whether its line count (e.g. wc -l) is equal to 2. if so, i want to append something. It must use only chain pipes.

start input:

```
echo "This is a
new line Test"
```

goal output:

```
"This is a
 new line Test
 some chars"
```

But only if start input line count equals 2.

i tried already something like:

```
echo "This is a
new line Test" | while read line ; do lines=$(echo "$lines\n$line") ; echo $all ... ; done
```

But none of the ideas got to the solution.
Using sed/awk, etc is ok, only it should be a chained pipe.

Thanks!

Comment: What does it mean to "use only chain pipes" or "be a chained pipe"? What's the reason for that restriction?

Comment: need to be a one-liner..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '1; END {if (NR <= 2) print "another line"}' file
```

Here's another way just for fun: bash version 4

```
mapfile lines <file; (IFS=; echo "${lines[*]}"); ((${#lines[@]} <= 2)) && echo another line
```

better bash: tee into a process substitution

```
$ seq 3 | tee >( (( $(wc -l) <= 2 )) && echo another line )
1
2
3

$ seq 2 | tee >( (( $(wc -l) <= 2 )) && echo another line )
1
2
another line

$ seq 1 | tee >( (( $(wc -l) <= 2 )) && echo another line )
1
another line
```

Comment: I'm curious why the `IFS=;` is there. To be consistent with the question, `<= 2` should be `== 2`.

Comment: mapfile without "-t" leaves the newlines in the array, so I want to explicitly join the lines with the empty string. The title says < 2, the question says == 2, so I assumed...

Comment: To be clear, `wc -l; cat` will undoubtedly be faster, certainly easier on memory

Comment: Re `IFS=;`: thanks for explaining; since the _body_ of the question mentions "equals" twice, I took the liberty of editing the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk it is much simpler:

```
[[ $(wc -l < file) -eq 2 ]] && awk 'NR==2{$0=$0 RS "some chars"} 1' file
This is a
 new line Test
some chars
```

Comment: But this will also insert "some chars if there are more than 2 lines in input... :( but thanks! better than my tries..

Comment: generally yes, but i can't do that: echo "..." | [[$(wc -l < input)]]

Answer (score 0):

This will only produce (augmented) output in case the input line count is 2:

```
 echo "This is a
 new line Test" | 
  awk \
  'NR>2 {exit} {l=l $0 "\n"}  END {if (NR==2) printf "%s%s\n", l, "some chars"}'
```